# How to apply and understand the pigeonhole principle in this question?

Tags: finite-fields, pigeonhole-principle

Now this question has been asked in this site and I am aware of that. But after some reading I still don't get the answer there.

This is a field with finitely many elements. I am asked to prove
that  a natural number $n$ is present such that:

[image]

based on other answers from quora: https://www.quora.com/Suppose-F-is-a-field-with-finitely-many-elements-How-do-I-prove-that-there-exists-a-natural-number-n-such-that-1-1-1-1-1-n-times-0

Almost everyone applies that pigeon hole principle. Many of the answers included said something like:  "there exists two elements in the sequence which equal each other."

I really don't see where (at least) two elements are equal to each other in the sequence? I am really confused on this part. I understand the lines after that (for example you can use the other element as an additive identity, if thats so, it is a field because $0$ - the unique element is present. But I don't get the two elements are equal part? How can I see this? Can someone provide another example in terms of math? Because I have read the wikipedia definition and that only make sense intuitively.

Comment: If the field has exactly 6 elements, and you choose any element $e$ from the field, consider the sequence of elements from the field formed by $e, e+e, e+e+e, \cdots, e+e+e+e+e+e+e$.  That is 7 elements from the field, but the field only has 6 elements.  Therefore, it is impossible for the 7 elements to all be distinct from each other.  That is, if they were all distinct, that would imply that the field has **at least** 7 elements, which contradicts the original premise that the field only has 6 elements.\

Comment: @user2661923 Why are you giving a full answer in the comment section?

Comment: @Arthur No, it is not a full answer.  This is different.  The OP has indicated that the OP has already researched the problem, been confronted with the pigeonhole principle, and is confused as to how it applies.  I am attempting to induce  a dialog with the OP, where the OP explains where they are stuck.  The OP has clearly shown *work*, and my analysis doesn't bring anything new to the table, so it is not an **answer**.  It is simply an attempt to draw the OP into dialog.

Comment: I fail to see how what you've written there doesn't address every single concern the OP has and answers them. They wanted an illustrative example, and you gave it. Had you given that an an answer, I would upvote without a moment's hesitation. But I guess we will just have to disagree.

Answer (score 1):

So, if I understand the question correctly, you have a fiinite field $F$ and you want to prove that there exists an $n\neq0$ such that
$$
n\cdot1_F=\underbrace{1_F+\cdots+1_F}_n=0_F
$$
*using the pigeonhole principle*.

I would do as follows:since $|F|<\infty$ for $k>0$ sufficiently large you have to find some repetitions in the sequence
$$
1_F,\quad 2\cdot1_F,\quad 3\cdot1_F,\quad...,k\cdot1_F.
$$
This is because the "pigeons", i.e. the numbers $\{1,...,k\}$, are more than the "holes", i.e. the elements of $F$.

So, let $r<s$ such that $r\cdot1_F=s\cdot1_F$. Then if $n=s-r>0$ we have $n\cdot1_F=0$.

---

I must say that this is a unusual way to prove the claim. The usual strategy is to observe that there's a canonical ring homomorphism
$$
\phi:\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow F,\qquad\phi(k)=k\cdot1_F
$$
and the finiteness of $F$ implies that $\ker(\phi)$ is a non trivial ideal in $\mathbb{Z}$, so that $\ker(\phi)=n\mathbb{Z}$ for some $n\geq0$ that in fact can be assumed positive and shown to be *prime*.

Comment: "since $|F|<\infty$ for $k>0$ sufficiently large you have to find some repetitions" The way I read the question, this is **exactly** the sentence the OP wants some expansion on. Why do you have to find repetitions? How does it link to the pigeonhole principle?

Comment: @Arthur, allright, I added a sentence making the appeal to the pigeonhole principle explicit.